# How do I get JSON data from an external file in jQuery and ensure the data is loaded before the remainder of the script

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I'm attempting to extract a JSON object from a .json file (hosted locally to the script) and saving the data as a variable. Currently, I'm using jQuery's `$.getJson()` function, which works fine, I just want to ensure that the JSON data is loaded before finishing the rest of the script as some functions rely on it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see documentation on [getJson](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

if you want it should run and other section should wait, you can set 'asysn' : false
but it is not a good idea, since the code after the ajax will wait until it completes.

OR

```
// check the meaning of done, fail, always
    $.getJSON( "url", function() {
    
    }).done(function(){
    
        // your rest of the code
        
    });
```

or you may try custom [trigger event](https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/)

```
$(function(){

    $.getJSON( "url", function() {

    }).done(function(){
        $( document ).trigger( "jsonSuccess", [ "bim", "baz" ] );
    });

    $( document ).on( "jsonSuccess",function(event, var1, var2){
        // will execute after the 'getJSON' success 
    });
    
    // other codes can be execute from here, it will not wait

});
```

Comment: Perfect, I think the custom event is gonna work best for my situation. Thank you